# What should I do when I'm done with a contextual reference acquired programmatically?

Tags: cdi

Suppose I acquire a contextual reference of a bean programmatically, using `BeanManager#getBeans(Type, Annotation...)` and `BeanManager#resolve(Set)` and `BeanManager#getReference(Bean, Type, CreationalContext)`.  (This is standard stuff.)

Suppose further that the bean in question is in `@Singleton` scope (it could be any scope other than `@Dependent`; I've picked `@Singleton` just (a) to make this concrete and (b) to get client proxies out of the picture to keep it simple).  (Note that strictly speaking I should be unaware of what scope applies to the bean I'm working with, but my question may be directly related to this.)

Suppose further that the bean in question has a `@Dependent`-scoped contextual reference "inside" it.  (This helps to highlight the necessary pairing of bean destruction with `CreationalContext#release()`; see below.)

Suppose further that the reference I get back is the first such reference.  That is, my acquiring this reference is what causes the underlying contextual instance singleton to be created.  All fine and simple and good so far.  Yay; I have my object.

I do whatever I'm going to do with this contextual reference.  Now I have just created something and don't want to leak memory, so…what should I do?

- Should I simply try to destroy the existing contextual instance underlying the reference, perhaps using `AlterableContext#destroy(Contextual)`?  But don't I now have to know intimate details about the scope and whether it is suitable to destroy any existing instance?  (And of course if I do this I'd better call `CreationalContext#release()` too.)
- Should I simply release the `CreationalContext` used for construction (without explicitly destroying the singleton instance)?  But this will destroy the singleton's dependent references.  That seems like something that would result in inconsistent state.
- Should I do nothing?  In the case of `@Singleton` this does no harm, since a singleton lasts for as long as the application, but, again, now I have to know intimate details about the scope.  Is this by design?

Is the proper answer *really* that I need to know lots of things about the particular underlying scope (which, if user-supplied, it may be impossible to do), and need to tailor my destruction/releasing actions to the semantics of the scope?

Comment: Couldn't you get the scope using the `getScope` method of the `BeanAttributes` interface extended by `Bean`?

Comment: Of course.  Now I need to look for a "special" scope value.  Why should I have to do that?  Either scopes are to be opaque or they are not, it seems to me.  Also: suppose a scope is user-supplied.  How will I know whether it is the sort of scope for which `release()` should be called or not?  Should I be looking only for `@Dependent` scope?  If so, why?

Comment: Yes, I think you should be looking only for `@Dependent` scope because  "Every invocation of the get() operation of the Context object for the @Dependent scope with a CreationalContext returns a new instance of the given bean.". (CDI 2.0 spec, sec 6.4, third paragraph). On other hand, beans in normal scope will be destroyed according to the lifecycle of the scope.

Comment: Thank you.  Suppose a user scope does the same thing.  How would I know?

Comment: The user scope implementation is responsible for destroying contextual instances when a scope instance is destroyed. But may be some use case requires a user scope implementation that behaves like `@Dependent`, and is always active. I guess you can't really know.